# How to integration between Thinktecture Identity Sever v3 and Authorization Server?

Tags: authorization, integration, identity, thinktecture-ident-server

I am setting up Thinktecture Identity Server version 3 (beta3), and it worked well. However I want to build a Role base security access control system to interact with Identity server to complete authorization.

So, I found Thinktecuture Authorization Server that implemented Claim-based access control. But after trying to search the integration with Identity Server v3, it just only shown results as integration with  IS version 2.

After reading some articles, I found Identity Server v3 have some features that do claim-based access control. But I'm not sure it completely do that?

So my questions is:
1. Is that Thinktecture Identity Server v3 included authorization features of Thinktecture Authentication Server?
2. If not, How to integration between Thinktecture Identity Sever v3 and Authorization Server?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IdentityServer v3 replaces the IdentityServer v2 + AuthorizationServer combo. IOW IdSrv3 has the authentication features of v2 and the OAuth2 implementation of AS.

We are pretty close to RTM with v3.

Comment: Thank you, I'am waiting for the next big release.

Answer (score 0):

I am playing with Thinktecture products for a couple days too and IMHO, they are trying to merge IdentityServer v2 and AuthorizationServer as a single Owin-compatible product with IdentityServer v3 and provide a UI to manage identities via IdenityManager.

Back to your question - I don't think IdentityServer v3 integrates with AuthorizationServer out of the box so i took the path of Integrating IdentityServer v2 with AuthorizationServer therefore authentication handled over IS2 and authorization provided by AS with Oauth2 protocol.

Yet, i still don't have a end-to-end working example even though i am able to authenticate via IS2 and get a token via AS, requests from clients still return unauthorized (these are samples from source code btw )